# Mongoose hide/show field based on another field value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model for a trade that looks like this:

```
{
  anonymous : { type: Boolean, required: true, default: false },
  name : { type: String, required: true }
}
```

I always store the name whether or not the user has chosen to be anonymous. But, I'd like to exclude the name field on a find() when anonymous is set to true. Even though the program needs to know the anonymous user's name, no other users should be able to see it. Is there a way to do this with a mongo query? I looked at the $cond operator, but it didn't seem to apply to this situation. I'd like to say something like "if anonymous is true, do not include the name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it looks on the mongo command line. The simplest solution I could find was using [$cond with the aggregate method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#example):

```
db.trades.aggregate([
  { $project: {
    anonymous: 1,
    name: { $cond: [ "$anonymous", "", "$name" ] }
  }}
])
```